# In B2C, how to change the MFA phone number or email or even change the method

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm using this [custom policy](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone) - "A B2C IEF Custom Policy - Sign in with MFA method choice (Phone/Email)". This works nicely.

The blurb says "with the ability to change this preference via Profile Edit" but I don't see this in the policy?

My use case is that the user can change the phone number or the email address for MFA or swop between the two (e.g. change phone to email and vice versa) in terms of MFA.

The easiest way is to "reset" MFA and ask the user to onboard MFA again.

So I set "extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" to "reset" and then the policy says:

```
<!-- If user is enrolled for MFA, ask the user to select the preferred method -->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                    <!-- If the preferred MFA method is 'phone' skip this orchestration step -->
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
                            <Value>phone</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                        <!-- If the preferred MFA method is 'email' skip this orchestration step -->
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
                            <Value>email</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                        
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method"/>
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
```

but I never see the "extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" radio buttons.

Are there other attributes I need to "reset"?

e.g. the policy uses "newPhoneNumberEntered" and "isActiveMFASession"?

Or is there a better way to "reset" MFA?

**Update**

I eventually got round this by [deleting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#deleteclaims) the extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" claim.

The user then has the choice of selecting email or phone for MFA again.

But if the user was using the phone already, it says "We have a phone on record" and no way to change it.

I got round that by using the "Edit MFA" [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/edit-mfa-phone-number).

Is there any way to clear out the phone number?

This claim is one of the ones that you cannot delete via the DelateClaims method.

**Update 2**

I included the DeleteClaims and the user journey piece that includes this.

If you still have issues, try commenting out the check for "extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail" in "SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method".

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-DeleteClaimsUsingObjectId">
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">DeleteClaims</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber"/>
    </PersistedClaims>
    <OutputClaims/>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common"/>
</TechnicalProfile>

<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="B2CUserProfileDeleteExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-DeleteClaimsUsingObjectId"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="B2CUserProfileUpdateExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
            <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>


<!-- If user is enrolled for MFA, ask the user to change the preferred method or the email or phone number -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Select-MFA-Method"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Hi , I am facing the same issue. can you please share your changes you did in custom policies to make it work , I am scratching my head from last 2 days to make it work. It works fine for new user the problem is just when resetting the MFA, thanks in advance

Comment: Done - as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail` as an output claim in your profile edit technical profile. The starter pack uses the technical profile called `SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate`.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L909

Then save the attribute to the directory by adding `extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail` as a persisted claim to technical profile `AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId`.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L796

You can read about output claims here for SelfAsserted technical profiles here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#output-claims

You can read about persisting data to the directory using the Azure AD technical profiles here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile