# how to change the MFA Phone number while enabling MFA in b2c sign up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, multi-factor-authentication

i have incorporated the MFA within b2c signup process successfully following **Local and social accounts sign-up or sign-in with MFA** starter pack in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-custom-policy), but i want to add the functionality to be able to change the phone number after code is sent with a ‘Go back’ button, while enabling MFA.
any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this live demo of changing MFA phone number in azure b2c by ***yoelhor***

[Azure AD B2C: Edit MFA phone number](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/edit-mfa-phone-number)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
    <TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"    TenantId="yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
    PolicyId="B2C_1A_Demo_ProfileEdit_PhoneNumber" 
    PublicPolicyUri="http://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Demo_ProfileEdit_PhoneNumber">
       
      <BasePolicy>
        <TenantId>yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
        <PolicyId>B2C_1A_Demo_TrustFrameworkExtensions_EditPhoneNumber</PolicyId> </BasePolicy>
    
      <RelyingParty>
        <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="EditMFAPhoneNumber" />
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
          <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
        </TechnicalProfile>   </RelyingParty> </TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i think i have not fully explained my requirement, i want to have the feature that while enabling MFA when user enters phone number and code is sent to his phone then on same screen there should be option of changing the phone number and send new code again to new number.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/18229970/imrankhan-mt any thoughts? i want to have an option for user to edit MFA number if he mistakenly entered wrong phone number

Comment: Please check this reference:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217523/in-b2c-how-to-change-the-mfa-phone-number-or-email-or-even-change-the-method
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988815/can-azure-ad-b2c-use-a-mobile-telephone-number-as-a-username